# How can I unite these two related queries?

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join, greatest-n-per-group, lateral-join

I have this query to check if a person is a customer or have been:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (person_id) person_id, person.name, 
      (CASE WHEN status = 'inactive' then 'Ex-Customer'
            WHEN status = 'active' then 'Customer'
        END) AS account_status
FROM person_subscription
INNER JOIN person ON person_subscription.person_id = person.id
ORDER BY person_id, status ASC
```

And I have this other query to get the locations:

```
SELECT   person_id, string_agg(name, ';' ORDER BY person_id) 
FROM    person_location WHERE person_id IN 
(SELECT person_id FROM person_subscription WHERE status IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY person_id;
```

How can I unite them and show person location as a single row on the first query?

Comment: The first query is missing an `order by` clause - without it, it is undefined which row will be picked when there are serveral matches per person.

Comment: @GMB I didn't copy correctly, it's fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I follow this correctly, you can use lateral joins:

```
select p.id as person_id, p.name, pl.*, ps.*
from person p
cross join lateral (
    select string_agg(pl.name, ';' order by pl.name) as as person_locations
    from person_location pl
    where pl.person_id = p.id
) pl
cross join lateral (
    select 
        case status 
            when 'inactive' then 'ex-customer'
            when 'active' then 'customer'
        end as account_status
    from person_subscription ps
    where ps.person_id = p.id
    order by ps.??
    limit 1
) ps
```

As commented already, your original first query is missing an `order by` clause, which makes it undefined which subscription status will be chosen where there are several matches. This translates as `order by ps.??` in the second subquery, which you would need to replace with the relevant column name.

Another flaw, that time in the second query in your question, is that the `order by` clause of `string_agg()` is not deterministic (all rows in the group have the same `person_id`). I ordered by location name instead, you can change that to some other column if you like.

Answer (score 1):

You would join it in:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (ps.person_id) ps.person_id, ps.person.name, 
      (CASE WHEN ps.status = 'inactive' then 'Ex-Customer'
            WHEN ps.status = 'active' then 'Customer'
        END) AS account_status
FROM person_subscription ps INNER JOIN
     person p
     ON ps.person_id = p.id LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT pl.person_id, STRING_AGG(pl.name, ';') as names
      FROM person_location pl
      GROUP BY pl.person_id
     ) pl
     ON pl.person_id = p.id
ORDER BY ps.person_id, p.status ASC;
```

I'm not sure what the significance of the `WHERE` clause is for getting locations, but you can include that in the subquery as well.

Comment: I get `missing FROM-clause entry for table "person"`

Comment: @MaddWorld . . . `person` is in your first query.  I just added table aliases.